# jQuery AJAX each not iterating as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I am using jQuery and I have script as below;

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.nm').each(function(row) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: 'id=' + 1,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
    $('.title').each(function(index){
      if (result) {

        $(this).html(result[index]);

        } else {
          $(this).html("&nbsp;");
          }
      });
  },
});
});
});
```

The script is suppose to change text in my table;

```
<tr class="nm" style="height: 30px">
        <td style="width: 15px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="section" colspan="5">Mix</td>
        <td style="width: 15px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="prev" rowspan="2"><<</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="next" rowspan="2">>></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="title" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="title" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="title" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="title" >&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="nm" style="height: 30px">
        <td style="width: 15px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="section" colspan="5">Mix</td>
        <td style="width: 15px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="prev" rowspan="2"><<</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="content">&nbsp;</td>
        <td id="next" rowspan="2">>></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="title" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="title" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="title" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="title" >&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

As you can see, the table has 6 rows, and it is in a 3 - row repeating format. The contents are filled by a test.php file which echos a JSON encoded array containing 5 members. In this way, all 5 cells having `class="title"` get populated successfully. But the second set with `class="title"` is not getting filled.

I made a `each(function(row)` to repeat the ajax call for every row having `class="nm"`. But this is not working. I think the `[index]` is not getting reset after ajax, because the remaining cells are populating if I provide more than 5 members in array. But I want the ajax request to repeat after every row having `class="nm"` and want to fill the data accordingly.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.title')` always selects **every** `.title` element. You are not restricting the set to any particular one. You have to make the selector dependent on `.nm` somehow.

For example:

```
$('.nm').each(function() {
   var $row = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: 'id=' + 1,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var $titles = $row.next().next().children('.title');
            if (result) { // it's enough to check *once* whether it is set
                $titles.html(function(index){ // easier
                    return result[index];
                });
            }
            else {
               $titles.html("&nbsp;");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This should work with the structure you provided. `$row` references each `<tr class="nm">` row and `$row.next().next()` will select second next sibling, which is the row that contains the `.title` elements.
It will break if you change the structure.

It would be better if you give the rows containing the `.title` elements their own class:

```
<tr class="something">
    <td class="title" >&nbsp;</td>
    <!-- ... -->
</tr>
```

Then you can iterate of those instead of the `.nm` rows, and get the `.title` elements with `$row.children('.title')`.

Comment: Hi,, can you make me a fiddle using your second suggestion?? giving the <tr> an id (`idaa` and `idbb`) instead of class?? :)

Comment: @blasteralfred: I was not talking about `id`s ;) Classes are better here. The code would be the same, but instead of `$('.nm').each(function() {` you do `$('.something').each(function() {` and instead of `$row.next().next().children('.title')`, $row.children('.title')`.

Comment: can u make me a fiddle?? :) i am a beginner.. :(

Comment: @blasteralfred: Here http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/fSezj/ I didn't make an Ajax request, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Hi felix, from your first answer, everything works well, but i have an ajax request designed to change background image of corresponding cell above title cell having `class="content"`. I want to do the ajax request to change bg image.. you can see my code here http://paste.pocoo.org/show/417349/

Comment: the data i get from the first ajax `test.php` is an array of 5 members, and each is an array with 2 members. I have data var values = result[index].split(','),
        indexa = values[0],
        indexb = values[1]; and cat represents data or text in cell or <td> having `class="section"`

Answer (score 1):

If your index gets larger than the size of the array returned from your AJAX call, you will refer to an index not present in the array. Have you considered using a modulo function on the index? Like:

```
result[index % result.length]
```

This should make sure that you never index outside of the array, and that as the index exceeds the size of the array, the [index % result.length] wraps to start from the first element again.

I am not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for... ?!?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning THIS into a variable before calling the second function (result)

I think THIS on each function is different from the THIS in the function(result)

```
each(function(row) {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'test.php',
data: 'id=' + 1,
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
success: function(result) {
$('.title').each(function(index){
  if (result) {

    $(this).html(result[index]);
```